# "Instance member 'makeAlert' cannot be used on type 'alert' " I can't fix this error

Tags: ios, swift

I created a new swift file and class. I want to use alert function all of my viewcontrollers. But I have an error. Here this is my class and function.

```
class alert {

func makeAlert(titleInput:String, messageInput:String){
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
       let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
       alert.addAction(okButton)
   }


}
```

I want to use my function here like this.

```
alert.makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: " name or Location can't be empty")
```

And here my error message:

Instance member 'makeAlert' cannot be used on type 'alert'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: `alert` should be `Alert` in the `class` declaration. Do you intend the function to be used on an instance of `Alert` or do you want it as a `static` function?

Comment: I'm not sure actually I just want to use this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert` is a type and `makeAlert` is an instance member. As the error says

> **Instance member** 'makeAlert' **cannot be used on type** 'alert'

To show the options let me first rename some terms of the code to avoid confusion

```
class Alert {

   func makeAlert(titleInput: String, messageInput: String) {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
       let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
       alertController.addAction(okButton)
   }
}
```

Either create an instance of `Alert`

```
let alert = Alert()
alert.makeAlert(titleInput: "Foo", messageInput: "Bar")
```

or make `makeAlert` a `static` function

```
static func makeAlert(titleInput:String, messageInput:String) { ...
```

then you can ***use 'makeAlert' on the type***

```
Alert.makeAlert(titleInput: "Foo", messageInput: "Bar")
```

For more information please read [Methods](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html) in the Language Guide

---

But an extra `Alert` class is not very useful and also the fact that the function doesn't have a return value. A better solution is an extension of `UIViewController` because you are able to present the alert controller in the current view controller

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentAlert(title: String, message: String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
       alertController.addAction(okButton)
       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer I deleted Alert class and I decided to use extension but how I'm gonna call presentAlert ? I try to "            UIViewController.presentAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Password or mail empty")
"  but I'm taking same error. I guess extensions have different call.

Comment: In the controller just call `presentAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Password or mail empty")` or `self.presentAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Password or mail empty")`. Please re-read my answer to understand the difference between *type*  and *instance*